# sql server creating foreign key as one to one not one to many (linq)

Tags: sql-server, linq, sql-server-2008

I have set up my tables like so:

```
Table A:
Id
[...]
```

```
Table B:
Id
AId
[...]
```

I have a foreign key created as

`FK_TableB_TableA` where primary key table is Table A and its primary key is Id and the foreign key table is TableB and its foreign key is AId...

However, when I update my dbml for linq TableB is defined as an `entityref` instead of an `entityset`...

Adding a foreign key should generate a one-to-many relationship correct?

This is very generic but if I need to add more detail please let me know!

Comment: `entityref vs entityset` ? please make it more clear

Comment: In the dbml.cs file you when it creates the classes when you have a one to one relationship the type of `EntityRef` and when you have a one to many relationship it has a type of `EntitySet<type>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't figure out why this was happening however on the dbml there was no association created between the two tables for whatever reason - therefore I just added the association.